# ng-click in ionic app doesn't fire on ios

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm having an annoying problem with the `ng-click` in my ionic app.

Here is the snippet where the problem is:

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">
  <ion-content has-header="false" overflow-scroll="true" padding="false" class="login">

    <img src="img/8ZehJaQ3RhWeZs5gIaNt_logo-il-club.svg" width="70%" height="auto" style="margin: 15%; width: 70%; height: auto;">

    <form class="list">
      <div class="padded">
        <ion-list>
          <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
            <span class="input-label login">Username</span>
            <input ng-model="data.cardnumber" name="username" type="number"  placeholder="Username">
          </label>

          <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
            <span class="input-label login">Password</span>
            <input ng-model="data.password" name="password" type="password"  placeholder="Password">
          </label>

        </ion-list>
      </div>
    </form>

  </ion-content>

  <ion-footer-bar>
    <button ng-click="login();" type="button" name="login" class="button button-full button-positive button-block footer-button " >LOGIN</button>
  </ion-footer-bar>

</ion-view>
```

What is weird is that this works on both Android and Google Chrome (with ionic serve), but not on iOS.

I tried replacing `ng-click` with `on-tap`, but it didn't change anything (still worked on Android and Browser, but not on iOS).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any errors in your `javascript console` or `xcode output`?

Comment: no errors, neither in javascript console neither in xcode output.

Comment: `on-tap` should be working on ionic app

Comment: yeah, i already tried 'on-tap', but it still works only on Android and browser

Comment: Did you try with <ion-content class="has-footer"> ?

Comment: Cannot image what the issue is. You should try to tear down your `<button>` without any extra `html` elements, `css` stuff, for example with a `<button ng-click"alert('Clicked')">Click</button>` Does the error persists?

Comment: @gadz82 , i tried both solutions, with no improvement.

Comment: are you using a stylesheet that is clashing with the ionic's own button?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<ion-footer-bar>
  <button class="bar bar-footer bar-positive" ng-click="closeModal()">
    <p class="title">Filter<p>
  </button>
</ion-footer-bar>
```

or

```
<ion-footer-bar class="bar-positive" ng-click="closeModal()">
  <p class="title">Filter<p>
</ion-footer-bar>
```